# SUM values from two tables with GROUP BY and WHERE

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables below named `sent_table` and `received_table`. I am attempting to mash them together in a query to achieve `output_table`. All my attempts so far result in a huge amount of duplicates and totally bogus sum values.

I am assuming I would need to use GROUP BY and WHERE to achieve this goal. I want to be able to filter based on the users name.

sent_table

```
+----+------+-------+----------+
| id | name | value | order_id |
+----+------+-------+----------+
|  1 | dave |   100 |        1 |
|  2 | dave |   200 |        1 |
|  3 | dave |   300 |        2 |
+----+------+-------+----------+
```

received_table

```
+----+------+-------+----------+
| id | name | value | order_id |
+----+------+-------+----------+
|  1 | dave |   400 |        1 |
|  2 | dave |   500 |        2 |
|  3 | dave |   600 |        2 |
+----+------+-------+----------+
```

output table

```
+------+----------+----------+
| sent | received | order_id |
+------+----------+----------+
|  300 |      400 |        1 |
|  300 |     1100 |        2 |
+------+----------+----------+
```

I tried the following with no joy. This does not impose any restrictions on how I would desire to solve this problem. It is just how I attempted to do it.

```
SELECT *
FROM
 ( select SUM(value) as sent, order_id FROM sent_table WHERE name='dave' GROUP BY order_id) A
CROSS JOIN 
 ( select SUM(value) as received, order_id FROM received_table WHERE name='dave' GROUP BY order_id) B
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the sums on each table, grouping by `order_id`, then join the results. To get the rows even if one side is missing, do a FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT COALESCE(s.order_id, r.order_id) AS order_id, s.sent, r.received
FROM (
  SELECT order_id, SUM(value) AS sent
  FROM sent
  GROUP BY order_id
) s
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT order_id, SUM(value) AS received
  FROM received
  GROUP BY order_id
) r
USING (order_id)
ORDER BY 1
```

Result:

```
| order_id | sent | received |
| -------- | ---- | -------- |
| 1        | 300  | 400      |
| 2        |      | 1100     |
```

Note the COALESCE on the order_id, so that if it's missing from `sent` it will be taken from `recevied`, so that that value will never be NULL.

If you want to have 0 in place of NULL (when e.g. there is no record for that order_id in either sent or received), you would do `COALESCE(s.sent, 0) AS sent, COALESCE(r.received, 0) AS received`.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nq3xYrcys16eUrBRHT6xLL/2

Comment: That is awesome! :) One question, if `sent` does not have an order_id 2, the `received` data for order_id 2 does not appear. Is there any quick way to still get the order_id 2 data?

Comment: @Dan Updated example for that scenario in answer.

Comment: You my friend are amazing. Thank you sooooo much. Works a treat. I will spend some time learning what is exactly going on here and develop my own knowledge now that I know this stuff is possible. Thanks again!